# How to catch and handle runtime exception in reactive java

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am new to reactive java with some basic knowledge. I am working on fixing a code piece where,

```
remoteHelper.fetchInfoFromRemoteHost(authToken)
.flatMap(response -> {
   //Process the response
 })
```

The `fetchInfoFromRemoteHost` method either returns a valid Mono or else can throw any runtime exception. I cannot change the method as it comes from a library.

How do I handle the case when this method throws a runtime exception? Cause I want to catch the runtime exception, wrap in a custom exception and rethrow or else process the valid response. In pseudo code, I want to do something like:

```
remoteHelper.fetchInfoFromRemoteHost(authToken)
.onError(e -> Mono.error(new CustomException(e))
.flatMap(response -> {
  //Process the response
})
```

Comment: Check Reactor 3 Reference Guide - Handling Errors https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which.errors

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, found at that there are two important concepts to understand before being able to handle this problem.

- Reactive pipeline assembly stage
- Reactive pipeline subscription stage

In simpler terms,

- **Assembly Stage** is when the reactive pipeline is being built and initialised but no subscriber has yet subscribed, hence no records are flowing through it.
- **Subscription Stage** is when the reactive pipeline has been successfully built and subscribed. This is the stage where the actual records flow through the pipeline.

If an exception occurs at Assembly stage (as in the above example), it will not be caught by any of the error handlers such as `doOnError`, `onErrorContinue`, `onErrorResume`, etc. However, if an exception occurs during the subscription stage, that'll be wrapped as a Error Mono and be handle-able via aforementioned handlers.

Ideally, `fetchInfoFromRemoteHost()` should not perform any non-reactive operations and should only return a pipeline that gets executed when subscribed. This way, we'll not have to handle the Assembly stage runtime exceptions.

Additionally, it is dirty but if we really want to handle a Assembly stage exception, we can wrap it in a simple try/catch.